# Where does CLion's CLangFormat take format settings?

Tags: clang, clion, clang-format

Where does CLion's CLangFormat take format settings?

I have settings in action I don't like. How to change them and/or how to force using of specific clang configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special CLangFormat edition. CLion is using LLVM implementation. There is the default settings, they are the same as LLVM `clangformat` utility has.
To change the setting, just create `.clang-format` file in your source root and follow [the instructions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) 
If you are using the latest CLion 2020.1 EAP, you can create this `.clang-format` automatically at the moment of `ClangFormat` activation of from the [export setting menu](http://helpserver.labs.intellij.net/help/clion/2020.1/clangformat-as-alternative-formatter.html#export-to-clangformat).

Comment: Important to note that CLion doesn't expose what version of clang-format it's using. As of writing this comment (October 2020) it's either using 9 or 10 but not 11.

Comment: @daniel That is easy to check - just run the `clang-tidy --version` from CLion pack. The internal ClangFormat has the same version.